# Gedit gktsourceview3.0 rules - multiple optional suffixes

Tags: regex, syntax-highlighting, gedit

I'm trying to write a syntax highlighter rule for arm assembly to use in gedit. In arm, every command has some optional suffixes which make it execute conditionally. So obviously I want the command itself to be highlighted, but also have it highlighted if it has a suffix. So, I created a keyword list that looks like this:

```
<context id="keywords" style-ref="keyword">
    <suffix>(ne)?|(cs)?|(hs)?|(cc)?|(lo)?|(mi)?|(pl)?|(vs)?|(vc)?|(hi)?|(ls)?|(ge)?|(lt)?|(gt)?|(le)?|(al)?</suffix>
    <keyword>add</keyword>
    ....keywords....
</context>
```

All the listed keywords get highlighted. However only [ANYKEYWORDHERE]ne [ANYKEYWORDHERE]cs get highlighted. It looks like it's only paying attention to the first 2 suffixes. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot really explain why your regex does not work.

Though I find it bit ambiguous and too complicated. Try:

```
(ne|cs|hs|cc|lo|mi|pl|vs|vc|hi|ls|ge|lt|gt|le|al)?
```

Comment: I'll give it a go. I don't actually know regex, so that abomination in the question is a bit of a random guess.

Comment: Well that worked perfectly. I know mine wasn't that easy to read, but I've no idea why it didn't work :D Thank you very much.